# CSS two nested DIVs with both 100% height don't work

Tags: css, html, nested, height

I have two nested `DIV`'s, the outer div (`div#wrapper`) has a `height` of `100%` which works fine, but there is a `div` inside `div#main` which should be `100%` but it is not. If I change `div#main` to `position:absolute` then it is `100%` but then the block is not in the wrapper anymore and gets out on bottom. Can you help me please...

```
html, body{
background-image:url(images/bg.png);
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

div#header{
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Firefox */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Safari, Chrome */
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Opera */
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* IE */
background:linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* W3C Standard */
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

div#logo{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;

background-image:url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:50px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width:900px;
}

div#wrapper{
border: 1px solid #00ff00;

height:auto !important;
height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
min-height:100%;
position:static;
width:900px;
}

div#main{
border: 1px solid #00ffff;
position:static;
height:100%;
height:auto !important;
min-height:100%;
margin-top:75px;
}

<div id="header">
<div id="logo"></div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have a `div`'s height set to `auto` along with something else at the same time!  `!important` over-rides anything else and your `min-height` is the same value as `height` so it's redundant and useless.  You're doing this multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```
div#main{
border: 1px solid #00ffff;
position:static;
height:100%;
height:auto !important;   <-- Get rid of this.
min-height:100%;
margin-top:75px; <-- Get rid of this.
}
```

Comment: In general, if you're using "!important" there's something wrong. If you know why you're using !important, it's time to re-factor your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Your `div#main` has no `height` of `100%`.

It has a height of `100%` + 2px border plus 75px `margin`.

Perhaps that might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this or not.

```
html, body{
background-image:url(images/bg.png);
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

div#header{
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Firefox */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Safari, Chrome */
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Opera */
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* IE */
background:linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* W3C Standard */
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
width:100%;
}

div#logo{
background-image:url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width:900px;
}

div#wrapper{
border: 1px solid blue;
margin:0 auto;
width:900px;
}

div#main{
border: 1px solid #00ffff;
height:100%;
}
<div id="header">header
<div id="logo">logo</div>
</div>

<div id="wrapper">wrapper
<div id="main">main</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, use z-index to get your header on top of the wrapper

```
html, body{
background-image:url(images/bg.png);
height:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}

div#header{
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Firefox */
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Safari, Chrome */
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* Opera */
background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* IE */
background:linear-gradient(top, #e5e5e5, #b5b5b5); /* W3C Standard */
border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

div#logo{
border: 1px solid #ff0000;
background-image:url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:50px;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
width:900px;
}

div#wrapper{
border: 1px solid #00ff00;

height:100%;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
top:50px;
width:900px;
}

div#main{
border: 1px solid #00ffff;
height:100%;
height:auto !important;
min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: He's not asking how to put it on top... he wants to know how to get it to 100% height.

Comment: Then remove the top:50px; and add margin-top:50px; on the div#main -__-' !

Comment: You don't see a problem in your `div#main`?  
`height:100%; 
height:auto !important; 
min-height:100%;`